# Removing map from ArcGIS Pro project using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I have a desirable requirement to be able to remove a map from an ArcGIS Pro project using ArcPy.

However the [ArcGISProject class](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/arcgisproject-class.htm#M2_GUID-1117B216-CE8B-47A9-998B-6143907D3165) does not seem to provide a method to do this.

Is it possible to do so by any other means from ArcPy?

Comment: You want to remove the map completely, or just so it's not an open tab?

Comment: Ideally I would remove the map, and any map frames in any layouts that use it, completely.  The less that is in a project the quicker it will open.  However, just being able to close the tab from ArcPy would be useful.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be a thing, yet.  I can't find anything like it in the 2.0 beta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have submitted an ArcGIS Idea for this:

[Removing map from ArcGIS Pro project using ArcPy](https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/13575-removing-map-from-arcgis-pro-project-using-arcpy):

> I have a desirable requirement to be able to remove a map from an
>   ArcGIS Pro project using ArcPy.
>
> However the [ArcGISProject class](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/arcgisproject-class.htm#M2_GUID-1117B216-CE8B-47A9-998B-6143907D3165) does not seem to provide a method
>   to do this.
>
> I would like ArcPy to be enhanced to allow this.
>
> My use case is a map automation application where I need to maintain
>   three maps to support three MGA Zones (Australian "equivalent" to
>   supporting three UTM Zones).  When the application exports a PDF at
>   the end I also save a copy of the APRX so that the user wanting the
>   PDF can, if need be, open up a copy of the project that created it
>   (think of it as a draft), and perform some modifications before saving
>   a final project/PDF.  Since each PDF only uses one of the MGA Zone
>   maps I would like to unclutter the project before saving the copy by
>   removing the other two MGA Zone maps.

Comment: Upvoted here + geonet ideas. I'm trying to script converting an MXD to APRX and need to delete the existing map after calling importdocument.

Comment: ArcGIS Pro 3.0 here, and still this crucial feature, especially for migrating ArcMap projects, ignored. Ouch. Promised for 3.1.